# java.io.FileNotFoundException Path to Resource incorrect

Tags: java, spring

I am using Java and Spring and Maven.  I am trying to get a handle on a resource, but get the following:

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /certificates/Apple.Push.Services.com.ionicframework.thewhozoo912107.cer
>   (No such file or directory)

As you can see below, the resource exists:

[image]

I try access the resource as follows:

```
private static String PATH_TO_P12_CERT = "/certificates/Apple.Push.Services.com.ionicframework.thewhozoo912107.cer";

    ApnsService service = APNS.newService().withCert(PATH_TO_P12_CERT, CERT_PASSWORD).withSandboxDestination()
            .build();
```

The code above is copied from a tutorial, so I am sure it is correct. What is not correct though, is the `PATH_TO_P12_CERT`.

**Question**

Please can someone advise what the path to the resource should be?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

If I add the following code, it does find the resource. So why does it not when I try access it via the `APNS.newService().withCert`?

```
InputStream is = PersonService.class.getResourceAsStream(PATH_TO_P12_CERT);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: I think the confusion is just: That `withCert` expects a "file system path", but you co/ame up with a "class path"..the `getResourceAsStream` converts/resolves this.

Comment: ..and there's a "jboss problem" i remember: Please check the content of /WEB-INF/classes/ (in the deployed container) ..is there a certificates folder?

Comment: @xerx593 The problem came from the leading `/` in the path.

Comment: @Nathan: Are you sure???

Comment: @xerx593 TO said it himself in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your path starts with a `/`, so it'll be interpreted as an **absolute path**, i.e. starting from the *root directory*. If you want to use a **relative path**, i.e. starting from the *root of your application*, remove the leading `/`.

So your path should probably be : `src/main/resources/certificates/Apple.Push.Services.com.ionicframework.thewhozoo912107.cer`.

Comment: Hi Nathan, thank you. That works. I appreciate the help.  p.s. not sure why someone down voted your answer.

Comment: yes, i see but it was someone else. I don't know why. Your answer is completely right

Comment: @MikeAdamenko Thanks, and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: ..i downvoted, because the answer is maybe helpful, but wrong!.. `/` is "home directory" only for "root". ..and if he doesnt want to use relative path? ...and WHAT is the root of application`?? ...you can remove anything else "leading" ...and what will you do, when 2 resources with same name in different "packages" (which would you relatively expect)

Comment: @xerx593 `/ ` is home directory for everyone, not only for root. If he doesn't want to use a relative path, he can use an absolute path (as written). And when two ressources are in two packages, they obviously have different paths, so there can be no confusion. I don't see what shocks you.

Comment: no, @Nathan, `/` ([Root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_directory)) is *not* [home directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory) for everyone (you maybe mixup with `~` ?)  ...he used the (correct) abosolute (class) path (..ran into problem -> posted the question)... and as long nor you nor he can say, where the file resides absolutely nor the "file paths of the class root(s)" (at runtime), you are far away from "the root" of the problem: You found a workaround, congratz!

Comment: @xerx593 Indeed, I meant `Root directory`. Thanks for the fix, I'll edit my answer.Thanks for the congratulations.

Answer (score 0):

`Class.getResource` can use a relative path or absolute path. The absolute path must start with a slash `/`.

However with `ClassLoader` only absolute paths are used, and a starting slash should be ommited. This will be the case in your original questiuon.